# Why am I getting ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
t = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile")+"\\documents";
string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var textfiles = txtfiles.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(t, x));
```

I want to get all text files from the documents directory and all subdirectories. Before I did this changes the code was:

```
string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And it worked.

But I did this changes since I want later to get the directory size and other stuff.
The problem is that on the line:

```
var textfiles = txtfiles.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(t, x));
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name
```

The variable t contain: C:\Users\bout0_000\documents
The variable x contain: C:\Users\bout0_000\documents\3DMark\3dmarkerror.txt

So why before it worked and after the changes I did in the code I'm getting an exception ?

Comment: You are calling `Directory.GetFiles` on a filename (.txt) not a directory

Comment: `i want later to get the directory size and other stuff` I think If you asked what you really want to do, you would get better answers.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to get a list of files using `Directory.GetFiles` on a filename not a directory path

I am assuming you want a list of the directorys that contained the files, so you could use:

```
   var textfiles = txtfiles.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your

```
var textfiles = txtfiles.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(t, x));
```

The `x` should be the search pattern like `*.txt` but your `x` here is not thus the error.

So, you could either did what you did like

```
var textfiles = txtfiles.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Or

```
var textfiles = txtfiles.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt"));
```